# share with facebook using Spring-Social and Spring Security

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I have integrated social sign-in button [Facebook] with my web application. Its working fine using spring-social and spring security.

In my login.jsp I have:

```
<!-- Add Facebook sign in button -->
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/auth/facebook"><button class="btn btn-facebook"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>facebook</button></a>
```

Now my registrion controller is: This is the place where I am getting a callback from facebook when the user tries to login for the first time from facebook and register the user in my Database.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm(WebRequest request, Model model) 
    {
        LOGGER.debug("Rendering registration page.");
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Connection<?> connection = ProviderSignInUtils.getConnection(request);
        RegistrationForm registration = createRegistrationDTO(connection);
        LOGGER.debug("Rendering registration form with information: {}", registration);
        model.addAttribute(MODEL_NAME_REGISTRATION_DTO, registration);
        return VIEW_NAME_REGISTRATION_PAGE;
    }
```

And also the user is getting saved in `UserConnection` table.

For subsequent login also I am getting the updated `connection` in my `WebRequest`

Now I want to create a `shareWithFacebook` operation for a user who logged in in my application using `signwithfacebook` button.

For this my controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String shareWithFacebook(WebRequest request){
  Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
  String[] head = request.getAttributeNames(WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
  String[] head1 = request.getAttributeNames(WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
  return null;
}
```

Now when I am running this controller in debug mode , then I can see the `Connection` object is present in my `WebRequest` object in this controller,
How I can use this connection Object to make any operation, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no help from stackoverflow: but actually I got the solution , may it help someone else, thus posting the same:

add this in your social-xml config to initialize `FacebookApiHelper`

```
<bean id="facebookApiHelper" class="org.springframework.social.facebook.config.support.FacebookApiHelper">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="usersConnectionRepository"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="userIdSource"/>
</bean>
```

Then use the same in ur contoller to work with existing connection object with facebook.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/facebook")
public class FacebookOperationController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FacebookOperationController.class);

    @Autowired
    protected FacebookApiHelper facebookApiHelper;

    @Autowired
    UserIdSource userIdSource;

    private UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository;

    @Autowired
    public FacebookOperationController(UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository)
    {
        this.usersConnectionRepository = usersConnectionRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String shareWithFacebook(WebRequest request,Model model){

        Facebook facebook = facebookApiHelper.getApi();
        Connection<Facebook> connection = usersConnectionRepository.createConnectionRepository(userIdSource.getUserId()).findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
        return "tilesname";
    }
}
```

Now we have `connection` and `facebook` , enjoy will all api..